# How to generate all numeric serial number?

Tags: security, random, numeric, nsnumber, serial-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create serial number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732480/how-to-create-serial-number-generator)

I wanna generate a huge amount of serial numbers for my software. The serial number

1. must be numeric only,
2. don't use any hardware info (hdd id, cpu id, macaddr ect) to verify it when customers type in,
3. the software doesn't need to connect to any server to verify it.

Is there any standard and secure algorithm to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with just using a Guid?

Comment: you need it to have a checksum?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger Guid uses hardware info.

Comment: @popnoodles ya, need a checksum for sure: to verify the number is genuinly issued from me.

Comment: @KenWhite not the same question. GUID has letters in it. I need only numbers. And the software needs to verify it (but no need connect to my server)

Comment: The second and fourth answers to that question will work, and the third can probably be adapted. The only way to verify it without connecting somewhere externally is by hashing it and comparing it to a previously hashed value.

Comment: @RichardSchneider it does? I guess you really do learn something every day.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Not if you use a version 4 GUID.

Comment: @DAVike: a GUID might contain letters when you write it as a string, but underneath it's just a 128-bit (16-byte) number.